# deploying assets to S3 via Heroku using assets_s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, assets, fog

I've followed the [guide from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31)
by adding environment variables and adding

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

to environments/production.rb

I see that the assets are uploaded to my s3 bucket and I can access them.

but on my website I dont see any assets that use the asset_path tag like on css

```
background-image: url("<%= asset_path "image.jpg" %>");
```

when I look at the source, I see a link to a file like this:

```
url("https://.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/image.jpg")
```

This is weird, since css and js works (using the FOG_DIRECTORY var). so why does FOG_DIRECTORY env is skipped here as if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by doing

```
config.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

and using

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between config.asset_host and config.action_controller.asset_host?  Trying to figure out how to use a CDN and a separate bucket for uploading images.

Comment: according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html it's the same thing `config.asset_host sets the host for the assets. Useful when CDNs are used for hosting assets, or when you want to work around the concurrency constraints builtin in browsers using different domain aliases. Shorter version of config.action_controller.asset_host.`